# Mouse hover is happening around the element not just on the element

Tags: html, css

When I place the mouse anywhere near to the right side of the element , mouse hover is displaying the list.I wanted it to be displayed only when the cursor is placed on the element. Please let me know how can i do that.

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> User</a>
       <div class="dropdown-content">
      <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></span>
      <a href="#">My Account</a>
      <a href="#">Logout</a>
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Post Your Ad!" Style="color:Red; padding:5px;"></input>
       </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rahul_16/MMHVv/24/

Comment: Please add your CSS or Javascript file, there is no mouseover event in your HTML code.

Comment: Please access to the fiddle... placed below the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a warpper to your user menu like this see
**Snippet**

```css
.dropdown {
bottom: 50px;
left:600px;
}
#usermenu{
  float:left;
  margin-right: 7px;
}
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

#usermenu:hover .dropdown-content 
{
display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn 
{
background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div id="usermenu">
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> User</a>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
   <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></span>
    <a href="#">My Account</a>
    <a href="#">Logout</a>
 </div>
  </div>
   <input type="button" value="Post Your Ad!" Style="color:Red; padding:5px;"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.But the two buttons seems to be very close. How can I create some gap between these two?

Comment: #usermenu {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 7px;
}  Snippet is updated

Answer (score 2):

Change your css to following:

```
.btn:hover + .dropdown-content 
{
    display: block;
}
```

from

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content 
{
    display: block;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMHVv/27/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just give a `float` to `.dropdown`.

```
.dropdown {
    float: left;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/MMHVv/26/)**

Comment: Thank you. It almost resolved. But still mousehover is displaying when the cursor is placed on "Post Your Ad!" button. I wanted it ot be displayed only for "User" icon.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this once

```css
.dropdown {
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 600px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<span class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> User</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></span>
  <a href="#">My Account</a>
  <a href="#">Logout</a>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Post Your Ad!" Style="color:Red; padding:5px;" />
</span>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMHVv/25/)**

Hope it may help you.